# Invoke-Expression cannot execute multi-line functions

Tags: powershell

I was trying to run a PowerShell script saved in a text document by using the following:

```
cat myScript.txt | Invoke-Expression
```

It works when each command is on its own line but throws an error saying I am missing syntax:

```
Invoke-Expression: At line:1 char:14
+ function foo {
+              ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
```

The code in myScript.txt is as follows:

```
function foo {
    param([int]$a, [int]$b)

    echo "$a + $b"
}
foo 1 2
```

Is there a way to run this script without changing the text file to merge all functions to one line?

Comment: `cat` is an alias for `Get-Content`, which by default reads the file one line at a time - each line is then sent by itself through the pipeline to `Invoke-Expression`. You can force it to read the entire file in one go by using the `-Raw` parameter: `cat -Raw myScript.txt | Invoke-Expression`

Comment: [DO NOT use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Using `-raw` allows me to do this, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you run this as a script?  `param([int]$a, [int]$b);
    echo "$a + $b"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [out-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.3) to convert output into string.

`cat myScript.txt | out-string | Invoke-Expression`